# Using JAVA for comparing values in different format

Tags: java

I wanted to know how you can compare two value in different format using java like 3k=3000 and it has to be set in a way it come out in a way where the code yields a pass or a fail

Comment: Uh....I don't get it.  This question is confusing.

Comment: I think they're asking for some type of inflector that could equate whether "3k" is equal to "3000".

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!  For future reference, we like to see questions that show what you have already tried (e.g. pseudocode).  For something like this, several example cases could help.

Per my understanding of this question, you want your program to receive input in two formats: the first input is marked with metric-style postfixes and the second as a standard integer.

Example Cases:

Input

```
1.000K 1000
1.123K 1000
1.1M 1100000
```

Output

```
Pass
Fail
Pass
```

To help with this problem, I would read about Regular Expressions (regex).

Perhaps write a method that would take the "non-standard" integer format as a `String` argument and return an `int` equal to the argument.  Then you can simply use the `==` operator.